# Code review for a self created .sty file

Tags: package-writing, code-review

I will start to write my masterthesis in the next weeks with LaTeX. I have build my own .sty and integrated it into my document. Everything works fine and it looks like it should but it would be great if some experts could look at it and give me some hints how to improve / upgrade my style :)

```
%% `MyStyle.sty'
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{comment}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{draftwatermark}
\RequirePackage{scrhack}
\RequirePackage[right=30mm,left=25mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[binary-units=true,locale = DE]{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{texnames}
\RequirePackage{paralist}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage[figure,table,lstlisting,equation]{totalcount}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{gensymb}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\RequirePackage{layout}
\RequirePackage{placeins}
\RequirePackage{chngcntr}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc]{glossaries-extra}
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\RequirePackage{media9}
\RequirePackage[autooneside=false,automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sortlocale=de_DE,natbib=true]{biblatex}

% Smaller underscore
\DeclareTextCommand{\_}{T1}{\leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule width.4em}}
% Enlarge equation vspace
\setlength{\jot}{3mm}
% Input variables
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
family=mysty@,
prefix=mysty@}
\DeclareStringOption{workString}
\DeclareStringOption{titleStringGerman}
\DeclareStringOption{titleStringEnglish}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{mysty@}
\newcommand{\workString}{\mysty@workString}
\newcommand{\titleStringGerman}{\mysty@titleStringGerman}
\newcommand{\titleStringEnglish}{\mysty@titleStringEnglish}
% Count words variable
\newboolean{myDraft}
% Enlarge table of contents page number space
\renewcommand*{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
% Pagecounter for optional pages
\newcounter{pageCounter}
% Setup bibiography
\bibliography{_Content/_Literature}
\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\newline{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{note}{\newline{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{\newline ISBN: {#1}}
% Format hyphenations
\hyphenpenalty=5000
\exhyphenpenalty=5000
\tolerance=5000
\hbadness=10000
% No pagebreak in literature
\patchcmd{\bibsetup}{\interlinepenalty=5000}{\interlinepenalty=10000}{}{}
% Clear default pagenumbers
\clearpairofpagestyles
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\chead{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
% Rename "Unterabschnitt" to "Abschnitt"
\addto\extrasngerman{
\def\subsectionautorefname{Abschnitt}%
}
% Show chapter name and section name in header
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markleft{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
% Counter setup for figures, equations and tables
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{figure}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\lstset{numberbychapter=false}
% Setup list of abbreviations and list of symbols
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
\setglossarystyle{long}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\begin{longtable*}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}{\end{longtable*}}}
% Long / short abbreviationstyle
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
% Listing definitions
\lstdefinestyle{CStyle}{
backgroundcolor=\color{GreenYellow!5},
commentstyle=\color{Green},
keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},
numberstyle=\tiny\color{Gray},
stringstyle=\color{Purple},
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
breakatwhitespace=false,
breaklines=true,
captionpos=b,
numbers=left,
numbersep=5pt,
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false, 
tabsize=1,
language=C
}
\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}
\lstdefinelanguage{json}{ 
basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily, 
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=8pt,
showstringspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
frame=lines,
backgroundcolor=\color{background},
literate=
*{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
{1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
{2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
{3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
{4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
{5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
{6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
{7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
{8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
{9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
{:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
{,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
{\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
{\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
{[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
{]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}
% PDF metadata
\hypersetup{
unicode=false,
pdftoolbar=false,
pdfmenubar=true,
pdffitwindow=false,
pdfstartview={FitH},
pdftitle={\titleStringGerman},
pdfauthor={MyName},
pdfsubject={\workString},
pdfproducer={pdfTeX \the\pdftexversion.\pdftexrevision},
pdfkeywords={\workString},
pdfnewwindow=true,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
urlcolor=black
}
% Macro to disable watermark
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9} 
\makeatletter
\def\watermarkoff{
\@sc@wm@stampfalse
}
\makeatother
\endinput
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My best wishes for you. Good luck :-)

Comment: there's not really a lot of code here to review, it's mostly a list of packages. `\hbadness=10000` looks wrong though, it says you don't want to be informed of bad layout.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right there isn't much code, but I thought about wrong / deprecated packages, duplicates or maybe a wrong package order... something like this which could take me a lot of time of searching while writing my thesis.

Comment: the best advice for a thesis (or any document) is don't include packages you don't use, so many people have issues as they start with a big preamble copied from somewhere that uses everything, but if you use all those, then not a lot can be said. But as I say the settings of tolerance and hbadness look suspect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I built up this preamble from the scratch and as far as I know, every package is used. I changed the values for tolerance and hbadness to suppress too many hyphenations.

Comment: hbadness=10000  doesn't affect the output it just turns off warnings even if the output is infinitely bad.  You asked for code review and I would never do that. It is impossible to comment on the  package list without seeing the document. If you use them, you need them, if you don't use them you don't need them.